# PyCharm errors (Can't install packages)

Tags: python, pycharm, package

So running the "pip install" command kept throwing a "Non-zero exit code(1)" *error*.  Then installing it through the command line would work, however, they wouldn't recognize the packages in the IDE.  I then uninstalled Python and re-installed and now it recognized the packages in the IDE but when I do "import pyautogui" and then try to run a line of code it gives an *error* saying "no module named pyautogui" even though if I run "pip list" the package is shown as installed.

I'm quite confused and I don't know why it's not working, I've been trying to figure it out for an hour

Also if I try to installed any package in the IDE it still gives me the "Non-Zero exit code(1)" so I can't even install anything....

Here is the actual *error* code it's throwing

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/AutoClick.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: _So running the "pip install" command kept throwing a "Non-zero exit code(1)" error. _ Was there any other output? How are you installing Python?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the python environment in your run configuration. ‍

Comment: To what?  I don't quite understand how it works.  The package is downloaded but it can't find it for some reason?  The environment variables is "PYTHONUNBUFFERED" and value is "1".  I don't know what that even means.

Comment: I use uninstalled PyCharm and reinstalled it and now it's working.